# How to get an auto modified field in django model?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

Say I have a model `User`, which has a `credits` field (`IntegerField`). When a user registers, I will set the `credits` field to `0`, and I will update the `credits` for certain events.

I don't want the user know there is a field like this in the db table.

What attribute should I set to the field?

Comment: a = models.IntegerField(default="wht u want")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish the defaulting to `0` part, you can simply use the `default` argument of the model field.

For the part where you don't want your users to know about the field, you have a couple choices.

### Solution 1: [`Field.editable`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#editable)

Defining your field as follows will cause the field to never show up in a model form.

```
credits = models.IntegerField(default=0, editable=False)
```

#### Downsides

1. You won't be able to edit the field's value in the admin
2. Form validation will never take this field into account (e.g., `def clean_credits(self):` won't run)

### Solution 2: [`ModelForm.exclude|fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#selecting-the-fields-to-use)

Creating a `ModelForm` for the model is something you're going to be doing. You can define an `exclude` attribute on the form's `Meta` class, and add `"credits"` to the list. See the docs linked above. You can instead define `fields` on the `Meta` class, and omit `"credits"`. The latter of the two options is considered a better practice, particularly when pertaining to security, and is known as a [whitelist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitelist).

#### Downsides

1. You have to remember to define `exclude` or `fields` on every exposed form

### Updating the "secret" field

The proper way to handle specifying a "secret" field's value when the field isn't in the form is:

```
# Inside your view's post method (or FormView.form_valid, if you're using generic views)
instance = form.save(commit=False)  # Does everything except INSERT into the database
instance.credits = <however many credits you feel like giving the user>
instance.save()
```

If you didn't do that, and instead just saved the form as-is, the value specified by `default` would be set to the instance's `credits` field.

Comment: For solution1: as I read the django code of Model, the default is supplied to ModelForm as it's 'initial', which means there should be such a field in this form.

Comment: For solution2: I think about that too, but how can I add the value as I supply value 0 when I create the Model instance? According to my last comment, I don't think default will do.

Comment: @dspjm regarding #1, there doesn't have to be a form field for `default` to function. If there is a form field, it will be provided as `initial` for the field as an added benefit, but the core feature is that creating an instance without a value set will result in the default. So, `instance = YourModel.objects.create()` will function just fine, assuming you don't have any other required fields without defaults, and `instance.credits` would be `0` after doing so.

Comment: @dspjm regarding #2 and also touching on #1 again (which I now understand where your concern is coming from), the solution has been added to the answer (see above).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use an IntegerField with default=0: `credits = models.IntegerField(default=0)`. Just take care not to show this field to the user in any forms or when displaying the user.

E.g., if you had a `ModelForm` for `User`, do not include `credits` in the `fields` field of `Meta`